# error: list of session IDs must follow -s

Tags: linux, celery, ps

celeryd is stoped working and its not starting.
i tried below code:

```
sudo nohup python manage.py celeryd &
ps -els | grep celeryd
```

and getting error:

error: list of session IDs must follow -s

Your valuable reply help me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

remove option `s` from your command. You should use:

```
ps -el | grep celeryd
```

if you read ps manual `man ps`

```
-s sesslist
          Select by session ID.  This selects the processes with a session ID specified in sesslist.
```

`-s` is used to provide a set of session ids to filter on which you are not passing. hence you are getting the error `error: list of session IDs must follow -s`